# Кодировка массива строк

Tags: c#, строки

Добрый вечер. Возникают проблемы с кодировкой. Задаю массив русских строк, на выходе получаю не читаемые символы.

```
static string[] from3till19 =
    {
        "", "три", "четыре", "пять", "шесть",
        "семь", "восемь", "девять", "десять", "одиннадцать",
        "двенадцать", "тринадцать", "четырнадцать", "пятнадцать",
        "шестнадцать", "семнадцать", "восемнадцать", "девятнадцать"
    };
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А Винда у тебя русская или английская? Если английская, то попробуй русскую локаль поставить.

Comment: File / advanced save options, поменяйте кодировку на unicode

Comment: @iluxa1810: Это какое-то очень глобальное решение для локальной проблемы. А если это сломает другие программы?